# Given list of horizontal lines in array, find the vertical lines that crosses the most lines

Tags: c++

## Problem

Horizontal lines such as (6 to 10), (9 to 11), (1, 20) which is point a to b are given and code should find a line that crosses maximum number of horizontal lines.

So, the following lines below, the answer is 3 because the maximum number a vertical line can be made goes through 3 lines.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM9zX.png)

```
6 10
10 14
1 5
8 11
13 15
10 12
12 16
2 7
```

Any suggestions for how to solve this problem efficiently?

## What I have tried

1. I have tried making an array and increasing the value of it by iterating through the line's starting point to the end. This way, the maximum number can be detected. Runtime error and the code is slow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int N, x, y, cnt, max_cnt = 0;
vector<pair<int, int>> end_points;

int main()
{
  cin >> N;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cin >> x >> y;
    end_points.push_back(make_pair(x, 1));
    end_points.push_back(make_pair(y, -1));
  }

  sort(end_points.begin(), end_points.end());

  for (const auto &e : end_points)
  {
    cnt += e.second;
    max_cnt = max(max_cnt, cnt);
  }

  cout << max_cnt;
}
```

Comment: Are the horizontal lines you are referring to in cartesian coordinates? Also, what do you mean by the answer is 3 in your above example?

Comment: populate two vectors of pairs holding the intervals, sort one according to start of the line the other according to end of the line, then walk both in parallel while keeping track of how many intervals you are inside and the maximum of that.

Comment: actually you only need vectors of int, one holding the start positions the other the end positions

Comment: "Runtime error and the code is slow." what error ?

Comment: You're not actually looking for a line. You're looking for the point of greatest intersection between a group of sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the example of two intervals

```
 0 1000000
 42 44
```

You don't need a loop from 0 till 1000000 to find that 43 is inside both intervals.

You only need to consider the end points of the intervalls. When they are sorted they are `0,42,44,1000000`. Then loop those end points. When the end point is the start of an interval you increment the count when it is the end of an interval you decrement the count. Thats 4 iterations instead of 1000000.

The following assumes that there is no overlap between intervals that have an end point in common, eg with two intervals (0,10) and (10,20) there is no point with count 2 (ie the intervals are open, for closed intervals only a small modification is necessary).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input {"6 10 \
                              10 14 \
                               1  5 \
                               8 11 \
                              13 15 \
                              10 12 \
                              12 16 \
                              2 7"};

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> end_points;
    int sta,sto;
    while (input >> sta >> sto) {
        end_points.push_back({sta,1});
        end_points.push_back({sto,-1});
    }

    std::sort(end_points.begin(),end_points.end());
    int count = 0;
    int max_count = 0;
    for (const auto& e : end_points) {
        count += e.second;
        max_count = std::max(max_count,count);
    }
    std::cout << max_count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Certainly got faster, but are there any ways to optimize it much more? I am solving a problem and your code is certainly faster than mine, but I did not solve the problem because the last 4 of them ran too slow.